# PHP with Zend Framework can't start a SQLite database?

Tags: php, sqlite, zend-framework

Trying to get a simple PHP/Zend Framework setup to create a SQLite databse and manipulate it.

```
<?php
require_once("Zend/Db.php"); // Zend framework
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Sqlite', array("dbname" => "./test.sqlite3"));

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$db->quoteIdentifier("configs")." (".$db->quoteIdentifier("name")." TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ".$db->quoteIdentifier("value")." TEXT NOT NULL);";
echo $sql;
$db->query($sql);
```

The SQL echoes out as "`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "configs" ("name" TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "value" TEXT NOT NULL);`", which looks right.

But I get a '`Zend_Db_Statement_Exception`' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 14 unable to open database file'. I've tried taking off the leading "./" on the "`dbname`" variable, and ensured that the folder the PHP file is in has write permissions for everyone. I even tried creating the file with "`touch test.sqlite3`" and ensured it was writable by everyone.

This is using PHP v5.2.10

Comment: Could you post the `Zend_Db::factory()` method source code?

Comment: @Alix it's online at http://framework.zend.com/code/browse/Zend_Framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Db.php?r=trunk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code is working here (on windows). so the `array("dbname" => "./test.sqlite3")` syntax is not the problem. as others, i assume it's a permission issue.

some ideas:

- if you are running the program with php as apache module: does it work if run from the command line? what are the permissions of the file created? adjust the permissions to the apache user accordingly.
- if above does *not* work: `strace` your script (`strace php test.php`) and check the output for permission errors.
- the directory where `./test.sqlite3` is to be created must be readable and writable by the user running php. it is *not* enough to have a readable and writable `test.sqlite3`, because sqlite also reads and writes a temporary `test.sqlite3-journal` file in this directory. make sure it is.
- try using an absolute path for the database name.
- make sure the `pdo` and `pdo_sqlite` extensions are loaded (check the output of `phpinfo()`). also, see that are no conflicts between the system and the php bundled sqlite libs.

Comment: Thanks Ax, I didn't realize SQLite needed a temporary journal file as well. Turns out I hadn't properly set the permissions on the folder to enable everyone to write to it, and once I fixed that, everything was great!

Comment: PRAISE THE LAWDZ. I've been trying to figure out for almost 3 effin hours why my application wasn't writing to the sqlite database. Like you said, I had to set permissions on both the .sqlite file and its directory. THANK YOU, ax.

Comment: In my case, to work, I just set the permissions (w/r) to the .db file and also for the database folder.